# Converting wp_remote_post to cURL in PHP

Tags: php, xml, curl

I have a wp_remote_post that is working on a different app:

```
$options = [
 'body' => [
 'xmlRequest' => $rawXml,
 ],
 'headers' => [
 'Content-Type' => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
 ],
 'timeout' => 60,
 'redirection' => 5,
 'blocking' => true,
 'httpversion' => '1.0',
 'sslverify' => false,
 'data_format' => 'body',
];

$response = wp_remote_post( $url_prod, $options);
```

I'm trying to convert this to cURL for a non-wordpress app, and getting the following error:

> "HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content
> length."

In my wp_remote_post i never defined content-length, so I'm wondering if that's not the issue and I'm missing something else. Here's the code for my curl:

```
$curlHeaders = [
'Content-Type' => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
];
$curlBody = [
 'body' => [
 'xmlRequest' => $rawXml,
],
];

//CURL setup
$sendRequest = curl_init();
curl_setopt($sendRequest, CURLOPT_URL, $url_prod);
curl_setopt($sendRequest, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($sendRequest, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($sendRequest, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($sendRequest, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curlHeaders);


curl_setopt($sendRequest, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curlBody);
curl_setopt($sendRequest, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$output = curl_exec($sendRequest);

curl_close($sendRequest);
```

I tried dynamically setting the content length in the headers, but got the same error. Any thoughts on what I'm missing?

Answer (score -1):

As seen in the document the value for [`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) has to be a string, not an array.
You can convert your array to a correct string representation with [`http_build_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php), e.g.

```php
curl_setopt($sendRequest, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($curlBody));
```

Comment: hmm interesting. When I do that, it's unable to read the required xmlRequest in the body. It then returns "Missing parameter: xmlRequest."

Comment: I'd go with `$curlBody  = [ 'xmlRequest' => $raxXml, ];`

Comment: The documentation you linked to says "This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value."